# Silverlight access Resource by Key from a CustomControl backend code

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

Scenario:

I have a view that has some DataTemplate resources

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDragCueTemplate">
        <Border Background="Blue"
                Opacity="0.5"
                Width="250">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I have a custom control derived from ListBox. Inside the custom listbox on a certain event I want to fetch a datatemplate from the View's resources.

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    public MyListBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyListBox);
    }
 ...

 itemDragCue.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["myDragCueTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

 ...
```

I tried adding the datatemplates to a separate .xaml file and added a ResourceDictionary, but it still didn't pick it up.

How can I get the resource in the custom control's backend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.Resources` will only give the resources declared in

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyListbox">
    <UserControl.Resources>
```

I would recommend putting myDragCueTemplate in a ResourceDictionary.  You will then have to read that ResourceDictionary in in your code behind, and extract the specific resource you want.

Try this

```
const string resourcesPath = "/AssemblyName;component/Resources.xaml";
Uri resourceUri = new Uri(resourcesPath, UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream);
ResourceDictionary dictionary = (ResourceDictionary) XamlReader.Load(sr.ReadToEnd());
itemDragCue.ContentTemplate = dictionary["myDragCueTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```